# Absolute position and floating

Tags: css

Do you have any idea, how to style this layout without specifing exact height for "Element 1"?

**Code**

```
Element1
{
positon: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto; /* I don't want to specify exact height */
}

Inner1
{
position: absolute;
top: xyz px;
left: xyz px;
}

Inner2
{
position: absolute;
top: xyz px;
left: xyz px;
}

Element2
{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

**Example**

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|Element1                                          |
|                              +--------+          |
|     +--------+               |Inner2  |          |
|     |Inner1  |               +--------+          |
|     +--------+                                   |
|                                                  |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------+
|Element2                                          |
|                                                  |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, i misread your question, you can't actually wrap around absolutely positioned elements because they are taken out of the normal flow and can not influence other elements.

You could probably work around this using JavaScript to get the bottom position of the absolutely positioned element and set your `Element1` to that or bigger `height`, or you could set `min-height` on `Element1` so it appears as it is containing the `Inner` elements.

Answer (score -1):

you could try putting a div with clear both set on it between element 1 and element 2

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```